# Process output not displayed correctly after read in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I seem to have come across what may be a bug in mono, or that Im doing something wrong.

I use subprocesses to do things via C# however in some situations the terminal breaks by not showing what Im typing correctly. Ive managed to get this down to happening after using the Console to read a line.

Im currently on a Mac using mono version Mono JIT compiler version 3.10.0, but dont know if this is a mono thing or it can happen on Windows.

The minimum code I have been able to recreate the bug in is bellow:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Console.ReadLine();

            Process.Start("tee","text.txt").WaitForExit();            
        }
    }
}
```

If you remove the read line, the output from tee will be printed after you input it (so you will see the same line twice) but with the read line it only displays the output from tee, not the input you type

IE:
Without the read line

```
~/test $ mcs program.cs && mono program.exe
this 
this 
is 
is 
writting 
writting 
to 
to 
file 
file 
^C 

~/test $ cat text.txt 
this
is
writting
to
file
```

And with the read line

```
~/test $ mcs program.cs && mono program.exe
readline
this
should
be 
printing
as well

~/test $ cat text.txt
this
should
be 
printing
as well
```